# Recursive iteration over JSON String (Google CSE result) in JAVA

Tags: java, json, recursion

I am trying to recursively iterate over all keys in a JSON String in order to eliminate all dots so I can use it for storage in MongoDB.
The string is acquired from Google CSE and then converted into a JSONObject.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

Then I use my recursive method to print all keys as a test

```
JsonTutorial.recursiveJSONCrawler(jsonObject);
```

Here is the method:

```
public static void recursiveJSONCrawler(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {
    String key;
    Iterator<String> iterator = jsonObject.keys();

    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        key = iterator.next();
        if(jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject){
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);
            recursiveJSONCrawler(jsonObject1);
        }else{
            System.out.println(key + " = " + jsonObject.get(key)+", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the (shortened) output:

```
kind = customsearch#search, 
title = mynews, 
request = [{"inputEncoding":"utf8","totalResults":"3660000","startIndex":1,"outputEncoding":"utf8","searchTerms":"exploit","cx":"004640873723005114527:yhaal5z_o0k","count":10,"safe":"off","title":"Google Custom Search - exploit"}], 
nextPage = [{"inputEncoding":"utf8","totalResults":"3660000","startIndex":11,"outputEncoding":"utf8","searchTerms":"exploit","cx":"004640873723005114527:yhaal5z_o0k","count":10,"safe":"off","title":"Google Custom Search - exploit"}], 
searchTime = 0.510257, 
totalResults = 3660000, 
formattedTotalResults = 3,660,000, 
formattedSearchTime = 0.51, 
items = [{"snippet":"Sep 25, 2017 ... The batch of more than 3,000 Russian-bought ads that Facebook is preparing to \nturn over to Congress shows a deep understanding of social ...","htmlFormattedUrl":"https:\/\/www.washingtonpost.com\/...<b>exploit<\/b>...\/4a011242-a21b-11e7-ade1- 76d061d56efa_story.html", ..... 
template = https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq={hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?} .....
type = application/json,
```

Why are does my method not iterate over elements within the 'items' tag?

Or maybe is there another, simpler solution for my problem to remove all dots from keys because they are not allowed in MongoDB?